Simulated Annealing - Graphical illustration
I'm in my first year at university and I'm supposed to prepare a small excursus for an exercise in which I introduce meta-heuristics and, above all, simulated annealing. First, the basic idea, how it works and the math. Then I want to show the basic principle using a small example so that you can better visualize the whole thing. The example will be a scheduling problem of doctors, which has the goal of minimizing understaffing. I only want to consider a short period of time and a small number of doctors, i.e. 3 days and 5 doctors with three shifts a day. How can I use such an example to show graphically how the swaps take place and also the whole thing sometimes with an improvement and then in the 3rd or 4th iteration but also sometimes with an iteration that then accepts a deterioration?

If you'd like to illustrate local search, you'd better go with the traveling salesman problem. A 2-opt move corresponds to removing an edge crossing. That's very visual
